# Error when adding Where or OrderBy clauses to Azure Mobile Apps request

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing an Azure Mobile App service to interface to my Xamarin application.

I've created, connected and successfully populated an SQL Database, but when I try to add some filters to my request, for example an `orderby()` or `where()` clauses, it returns me a Bad Request error.
For example, this request: `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/Race?$orderby=iRound%20desc,iYear%20desc&$top=1&ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0` gives me `{"message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'IYear' on type 'MyType'."}`.

My configuration method is this:

```cs
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .AddTablesWithEntityFramework()
                .ApplyTo(config);
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MainDataContext>());
app.UseWebApi(config);
```

and my DbContext is this:

```cs
public class MainDataContext : DbContext
{
    private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

    public MainDataContext() : base(connectionStringName)
    {
        Database.Log = s => WriteLog(s);
    }

    public void WriteLog(string msg)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
            new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
    }

    public DbSet<Race> Race { get; set; }
    public DbSet ...ecc...
}
```

Following [this](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/) guide, I added a migration after creating my TableControllers. So the TableController for the example type shown above is pretty standard:

```cs
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public class RaceController : TableController<Race>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MainDataContext context = new MainDataContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Race>(context, Request);
    }

    // GET tables/Race
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IQueryable<Race> GetAllRace()
    {
        return Query();
    }

    // GET tables/Race/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<Race> GetRace(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/Race/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Race> PatchRace(string id, Delta<Race> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/Race
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostRace(Race item)
    {
        Race current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/Race/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteRace(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I already tried to add the EnableQuery attribute to my TableController, as seen on Google. I also tried to add these filters to the HttpConfiguration object, without any success:

```cs
config.Filters.Add(new EnableQueryAttribute
{
    PageSize = 10,
    AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.All,
    AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.All,
    AllowedLogicalOperators = AllowedLogicalOperators.All,
    AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All
});
config.AddODataQueryFilter(new EnableQueryAttribute
{
    PageSize = 10,
    AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.All,
    AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.All,
    AllowedLogicalOperators = AllowedLogicalOperators.All,
    AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All
});
```

I don't know what to investigate more, as things seems to be changing too fast for a newbie like me who's first got into Azure.

EDIT

I forgot to say that asking for the complete table, so for example `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/Race?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0`, returns correctly the entire dataset. The problem occurs only when adding some clauses to the request.

EDIT 2

My model is like this:

```cs
public class Race : EntityData
{
    public int iRaceId { get; set; }
    public int iYear { get; set; }
    public int iRound { get; set; }

    ecc..
}
```

and the database table that was automatically created is this, including all the properties inherited from EntityData:

[Database table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clAXy.jpg)

Comment: are **iRound** and **iYear** fields part of result-set?

Comment: I personally don't think its a good idea to have an SQL connection in a mobile application, why are you not using a web-api for this

Comment: iRound and iYear are **properties** of my model class

Comment: I'm not connecting directly to the database; in fact, I'm using a web-api for this, as you can see from the example url I left above.

Comment: Please add the model and what the database table schema looks like right now

Comment: There you have it

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the source code, Azure Mobile Apps sets up camelCase encoding of all requests and responses.  It then puts them back after transmission accordign to rules - so iRaceId becomes IRaceId on the server.

The easiest solution to this is to bypass the auto-naming and use a JsonProperty attribute on each property within your server-side DTO and client-side DTO so that they match and will get encoding/decoded according to your rules.

So:

```cs
public class Race : EntityData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("raceId")]
    public int iRaceId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public int iYear { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("round")]
    public int iRound { get; set; }

    etc..
}
```